# Prevent pressing dot key in React Native numeric type keyboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I developed an application where user can enter their mobile numbers and I want to prevent users from pressing the dot and dash key, How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [react-phone-number-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input/react-native-input'

function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return (
    <PhoneInput
      style={...}
      defaultCountry="US"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue} />
  )
}
```

see here [demo](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/)

To display number phone you can use formater

```
import { formatPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input'
formatPhoneNumber('+12133734253') === '(213) 373-4253'
```

then put in text

```
<Text>
  {formatPhoneNumber('+12133734253')}
</Text>
```

Comment: But this one always says "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component" how can i resolve it

Comment: it still says the same error,

Comment: i used same code as you mentioned

Comment: @RajaKing which error?

Comment: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Comment: This Error: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Comment: @RajaKing
how do you render it, you can share your code?

Comment: const DoctorsScreen = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <PhoneInput
          placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
          onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}
          value={value}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

Comment: @RajaKing if you want only to display it, you can use only the text component.
 updated my answer for you

Comment: it works but formik handle change shows can not read property persist of undefined. can I use it with formik or not?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of not integrating a third party package just to check the phone number, you can simply create a regex that matches dot and dash keys and show a message "Please don't use "-" and "." while users are entering their phone number. This solution will provide more space for you to tweak things later if the needs from this component changes.

Comment: but i want to prevent not validate, is there any other option?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you can disable the call to action in case of the regex validation fails and show the aforementioned message. That way you can have a dependency free solution.